# How are percentage based paddings determined?

Tags: css

I'm aware from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) that percentage based paddings use their containing block to determine their width.

But what is the containing block in this example?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Style:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#outer {
    width: 100px;
}

#inner {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5%;
}
```

Is the padding of `#inner` calculated to be at `2.5px` or `5px`? Any links to the spec and/or external sources that can explain what is happening and why in further detail will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**Box model - 8.4 Padding properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties)
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block.

Therefore, the padding of `#inner` would be based on the containing block, which in this instance would be the parent element, `#outer`.

The padding of `#inner` would be `5%`. (confirmed by checking computed styling in dev tool)

> [**Visual formatting model - 9.1.2 Containing blocks**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block)
>
> In general, generated boxes act as containing blocks for descendant boxes; we say that a box "establishes" the containing block for its descendants. The phrase "a box's containing block" means "the containing block in which the box lives," not the one it generates.

Comment: So this is regardless of whatever width is set for `#inner`?

Comment: It seemed strange to me that it would work like this but thank you. This clarifies it for me.

Comment: @DaxKieran That seems to be correct - yes. In this instance, the `width` of `#inner` wouldn't effect the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

> "Percentages refer to the width of the containing block.."